# Deploying a directory hierarchy alongside an exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I am deploying an application using ClickOnce. I can successfully include additional runtime dependencies (as long as they are files) by adding them to my exe assembly project with a Build Action of "Content". These files are placed alongside my exe when the application is installed via ClickOnce.

I need do the same thing for a folder hierarchy. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you application check and create it at startup.